# How do I create Windows in D with win32?

Tags: winapi, d, win32gui

Hello I'm trying to open a window with win32 in D, and I've got a little problem. The program crashes when I call CreateWindowA.

Here is my code :

```
this.fenetrePrincipale = CreateWindowA(this.classeFenetre.lpszClassName, toStringz(title), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 100, 100, null, null, this.hInstance, null);
```

with:

```
this.classeFenetre.lpszClassName = toStringz("classeF");
this.hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(null);
```

and

```
string title = "test";
```

When I launch the exe, the program crashes and I've got:

> Process terminated with status -1073740791

on code::blocks.

Answer (score 11):

The error code -1073740791 (or 0xc0000409) is caused by a stack buffer overrun (not overflow, as in running out of stack, but writing to a place in stack where you are not supposed to write to).

The call that you've shown is looks OK. But you didn't show us the class registration code, and more importantly, the `WndProc` you register. I am not sure how you do it in D, but your `WndProc` needs to be declared `__stdcall`, so that it matches the calling convention assumed by Windows. This is a common problem that causes crashes on `CreateWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that was the problem :

I didn't declared the WndProc as __stdcall
the way you do that in D is

```
extern (Windows) int windowRuntime(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Note this is not a forum, but a Q&A site, and as such you've posted an "answer". If you want to comment on an answer, click the comment button below it. If an answer is satisfactory, accept it by clicking the check mark. As for this "answer", you ought to delete it. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using gtkD or QTD instead of Win32. The two widget libraries are mature and powerful, yet very simple to use. And you have cross-platform support as well.

Comment: In fact my aim is to create a 2D API from nothing.
I don't want to create a proffessional like QT or GTK, more like sdl.

Comment: Why? Does it worth it to reinvent the wheel? In this case, there are some other GUI toolkit, although they are not mature yet, are written entirely in D. You can learn from their source code. And MSDN documentations is extremely valuable.